# Error when trying to load custom theme in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, yo

What I did:

1. `npm install -g yo generator-code`
2. `yo code` and selected New Color Theme
3. Following instructions for name, author etc.
4. The ready made folder I moved to $HOME/.vscode/extensions (I am on Mac)

Content of my folder:

[image]

Inside the themes folder:

[image]

I restarted the vscode and from Code->Preferences->Color Theme I chose my theme and have the following error:

[image]

The theme was generated with [editor](https://tmtheme-editor.herokuapp.com). I also tried with theme from [colorsublime](http://colorsublime.com/) but I had the same error.

This is package.json file:

```
    {
    "name": "random",
    "displayName": "randomtheme",
    "description": "theme",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "publisher": "Milenito",
    "engines": {
        "vscode": "^1.5.0"
    },
    "categories": [
        "Themes"
    ],
    "contributes": {
        "themes": [
            {
                "label": "Random",
                "uiTheme": "vs-dark",
                "path": "./themes/milenekai.tmTheme"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I really can't see where is the problem. I would appreciate any help.